# ReferenceError js Function not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshAgonas is not defined "

The players div is filled correctly. Do I need some kind of special define with the JS functions in the JS file?

```
<html>    
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-draw.js"></script>
  <h2>Game</h2> 
  <div class="agonas">
    <script>
        setInterval(refreshAgonas, 5000);
        var inRequesG = false;
    </script>
  </div>
  <h2>Players</h2>
  <div class="players">
    <script>
      setInterval(refreshPlayers, 5000);
      var inRequest = false;
    </script>
  </div>

</html>
```

jquery-draw.js

```
   function refreshPlayers() {
    if (inRequest) {
        return false;
    }
    inRequest = true;
    var load = $.get('playersdata.php');
    $(".players").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function () {
        console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
        $(".players").html('failed to load');
        // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function (res) {
        console.log("Success");
        $(".players").html('<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>League</th><th>Sex</th><th>Birthday</th></tr>' + res + '</table>');
    });
    load.done(function () {
        console.log("Completed");
        inRequest = false;
    });
}

function refreshAgonas() {
    if (inRequestG) {
        return false;
    }
    inRequestG = true;
    var load = $.get('playersdata.php');
    $(".agonas").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function () {
        console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
        $(".agonas").html('failed to load');
        // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function (res) {
        console.log("Success");
        $(".agonas").html('<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>League</th><th>Sex</th><th>Birthday</th></tr>' + res + '</table>');
    });
    load.done(function () {
        console.log("Completed");
        inRequestG = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to the JS file is correct? Try adding "../" or other elements that would help the browser located the file.

Comment: Both functions are in the jquery-draw.js file. Why would refreshPlayers work and refreshAgonas not? Maybe i'm supposed to declare them with some other way? i dk

Comment: Are you sure the players one is loading? Do you see the console.log("success") ?

Comment: yes here you go http://i43.tinypic.com/14lpzzc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I saw the problem:

Replace

```
var inRequesG = false;
```

With

```
var inRequestG = false;
```

You forgot the "t"

Comment: This is indeed a problem but I don't think it would cause the uncaught reference error

Comment: Indeed it doesn't make sense although i had it corrected before you mentioned it. But for some reason it runs smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the functions like this:

```
var refreshPlayers = function () {};
var refreshAgonas = function () {};
```

Try this and respond with the results.

EDIT: didn't mean to include the parenthesis.

Comment: Yeap figured that out, still nothing though. Players div is filled fine, agonas nothing

Comment: How about putting the code you need in the document load event?

Comment: Not familiar with the method, let me look it up and give it a try

Comment: In a header script tag add: $( function () { //doStuff } ); You can find more here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
setInterval( refreshAgonas, 5000);
```

With this:

```
setInterval(function(){ refreshAgonas()}, 5000);
```

Comment: only difference now is that is shows the Ref Error again and again in the console

Comment: This could work if `refreshAgonas` would be defined later, but I don't think that's the case. Evenso you should resolve the define issue and not add silly workarounds.